# Exporting test results to excel

Tags: watir

I am running a test on watir through command line interface.

what I want is, when the watir has finished running last line of instructions, it should export message in excel saying eg. "test case 1 passed." or "test case 1 failed".

I am using Watir

Comment: Which test framework are you using? Getting the test case result would depend on the framework being used.

Comment: Watir itself is not a test framework. Watir is just a tool for driving browsers. Usually people use a test framework such as Cucumber, RSpec, Test-Unit or Minitest for the actual tests/reporting. If you share some of your code and what you have tried, it might help us to find a solution that integrates well with what you have.

Comment: I am afraid that I am not using any framework in that case then. I was given this exercise to write test script for our login page using Watir. which I have already done. Now I am thinking bit further to handle test results by exporting them to Excel. I am not sure how can I incorporate test framework into my test. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write to excel, there are various gems (libraries) you can use. Here are a couple of options.

**win32ole**

There are various gems out there that can write excel files. Personally, I use the win32ole gem since it does not require additional gems to be installed.

An example of creating an excel file with this gem is:

```
require 'win32ole'
excel = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
excel.visible = true
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
worksheet.Range("A1:B1").value = ["Test","Result"]
worksheet.Range("A2:B2").value = ["Test Name 1", "Pass"]
```

You can add formatting, etc - see http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/03/27/using-ruby-and-win32ole-to-manipulate-excel/

**CSV**

If you do not need any formatting, you might consider creating a csv file using the [CSV gem](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html).

An example of creating a csv file with this gem is:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("C:/Users/user/Desktop/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Test","Result"]
  csv << ["Test Name 1", "Pass"]
end
```

See the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi Justin, I am also using WIN32OLE and also I am using ADODBConnecter(only when I want to write the query). But you see this WIN32OLE is not compatible with Ruby 64 bit interpreter. What did you do for that?

Comment: @Gopal, unfortunately, I haven't had to deal with that problem. I have stuck to using the 32-bit version.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Even I am using 32 bit version, But If I want to move 64 bit Ruby then this is obstructing me.